# NavUtils navigateUpFromSameTask() and onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and I'm facing a problem.
I've got an activity, which contains a ListFragment. After the list item is tapped the new Activity starts. I decided to do a back Navigation in a child Activity with the Home button on the Menu bar.

```
if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null){
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

....

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null){
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And I also need to save the integer value into the parent Activity. So I override the onSaveInstanceState()

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("ACTIVITY_STATE", " onSave");
    savedInstanceState.putInt(TAG_INT_VAL_SAVED, intVal);
}
```

But when I tap on the back arrow at the child Activity and the onCreate method of the parent Activity is called, it appears that the parameter Bundle is null, up to the Log of the following code...

```
if (savedInstanceState != null){
        intVal = savedInstanceState.getInt(TAG_INT_VAL_SAVED);
        Log.d("ACTIVITY_STATE", " onSave getting data"); // Never appears at LogCat
    } else {
        // code to assign intVal as if the Activity was just started
    }
```

I'm a little confused, so I'd like to ask you, guys, for a help. Could you please tell, what's going on, when the navigation happens? And what should I do, to keep the intVal saved? Thank you!

B.t.w. It works fine on the screen rotation - the value is successfully retrieved.

The manifest looks like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ListItemActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MyListActivity"/>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MyListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```